# R Highcharter map with hc_motion

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization, r-highcharter

I am trying to use the highcharter  in R to create a motion map like this one http://jkunst.com/r/adding-motion-to-choropleths/
But I have a problem: the data is not visualized
[image]

```
df<-structure(list(fips = c("ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", 
"ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", 
"ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", 
"ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", 
"CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", 
"CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", 
"CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", 
"DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", 
"DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", 
"DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "GBR", "GBR", 
"GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", 
"GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", 
"GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "ITA", 
"ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", 
"ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", 
"ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", 
"ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", 
"ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", 
"ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", "ROU", 
"ROU", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", 
"RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", 
"RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", 
"RUS", "RUS", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA"), sm = c("Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", 
"Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017", 
"Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", "Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", 
"Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", 
"Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", 
"Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", 
"Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017", "Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", 
"Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", 
"Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", 
"Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", 
"Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", 
"Apr 2017", "May 2017", "Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", "Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", 
"Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", 
"Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", 
"Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", 
"Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017", 
"Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", "Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", 
"Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", 
"Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", 
"Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", 
"Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017", "Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", 
"Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", 
"Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", 
"Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", 
"Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", 
"Apr 2017", "May 2017", "Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", "Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", 
"Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", 
"Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", 
"Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", 
"Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017", 
"Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", "Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", 
"Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", 
"Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", 
"Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", 
"Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017", "Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", 
"Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", 
"Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", "Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", 
"Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Dec 2018", "Sep 2016", 
"Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", 
"Apr 2017", "May 2017", "Jun 2017", "Jul 2017", "Aug 2017", "Sep 2017", 
"Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017", "Jan 2018", "Feb 2018", "Mar 2018", 
"Apr 2018", "May 2018", "Jun 2018", "Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", 
"Oct 2018", "Nov 2018", "Dec 2018"), value = c(0, 13, 1397, 12134, 
6938, 13193, 6947, 6990, 7112, 7233, 13838, 18109, 9700, 19612, 
18048, 6441, 7528, 9947, 8073, 5862, 5991, 5501, 6294, 6960, 
5350, 4479, 3612, 3143, 0, 12845, 28060, 35813, 37810, 35687, 
39469, 37079, 34033, 29262, 31483, 29198, 22719, 19749, 17035, 
18740, 19646, 16118, 18970, 18930, 23074, 22650, 25215, 23299, 
21329, 19246, 20893, 17106, 0, 11964, 33654, 54440, 51427, 55324, 
51136, 41176, 40035, 33106, 34155, 34207, 26175, 21376, 16997, 
17213, 18211, 15071, 17266, 15598, 15431, 16155, 16082, 18322, 
17276, 17654, 17282, 14001, 0, 737, 3225, 9009, 9324, 9780, 7361, 
7584, 12033, 24794, 25236, 27493, 27189, 20672, 17579, 17706, 
19280, 17461, 18950, 14288, 15485, 15241, 15148, 16124, 14720, 
15279, 16888, 13580, 0, 4020, 21926, 27982, 32928, 39744, 46413, 
34679, 35026, 32160, 33611, 33234, 29394, 23364, 20977, 23407, 
26501, 21561, 23497, 20090, 21115, 18817, 18255, 21492, 21852, 
19908, 18862, 16447, 0, 218, 2611, 8126, 5907, 10862, 5104, 4956, 
13169, 22457, 25120, 18480, 15580, 14720, 13146, 16750, 16321, 
18067, 15336, 13460, 12949, 9010, 10691, 12153, 13791, 16114, 
12893, 10122, 0, 60, 1143, 4251, 3754, 6211, 3291, 2570, 5673, 
8171, 9279, 12914, 9675, 7521, 5621, 9473, 7104, 12808, 10212, 
8591, 6588, 5055, 6374, 6811, 8072, 11054, 9431, 9558, 0, 122, 
1004, 2713, 2554, 2642, 3946, 4355, 3526, 3945, 3792, 5631, 7642, 
11354, 13887, 12825, 16926, 15920, 14848, 13762, 13429, 10786, 
11194, 11214, 9251, 11578, 13808, 14115, 2, 43253, 213319, 332907, 
366366, 368012, 392814, 302207, 283924, 260065, 274796, 269966, 
235781, 190387, 166872, 195390, 207261, 166208, 176403, 178703, 
192598, 191750, 207203, 211225, 184818, 192932, 214297, 179867
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-252L))

my_ds <- df %>% 
  group_by(fips) %>% 
  do(item = list(
    fips = first(.$fips),
    sequence = .$value,
    value = first(.$value))) %>% 
  .$item


url <- "https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"
tmpfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")
download.file(url, tmpfile)
us <- readLines(tmpfile)
us <- gsub(".* = ", "", us)
map <- jsonlite::fromJSON(us, simplifyVector = FALSE)


highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = my_ds,
                mapData = map,
                joinBy = "fips",
                borderWidth = 0.01) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops()) %>%  
  hc_title(text = "How the Epidemic of Drug Overdose Deaths Ripples") %>% 
  hc_legend(layout = "vertical", reversed = TRUE,
            floating = TRUE, align = "right") %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) %>% 
  hc_motion(
    enabled = TRUE,
    axisLabel = "year",
    labels = unique(as.character(df$sm)),
    series = 0,
    updateIterval = 50,
    magnet = list(
      round = "floor",
      step = 0.1
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the map data of the world you use has no `fips` (these are US county codes) so `joinBy="fips"` cannot work the way you expect it to.

The country codes of your dataset correspond to the worldmaps `iso-a3` codes. If you use these instead of `fips` it will work as expected:

```
my_ds <- df %>% rename(`iso-a3` = fips) %>% 
  group_by(`iso-a3`) %>% 
  do(item = list(
    `iso-a3` = first(.$`iso-a3`),
    sequence = .$value,
    value = first(.$value))) %>% 
  .$item

highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = my_ds,
                mapData = map,
                joinBy = "iso-a3",
                borderWidth = 0.01) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops()) %>%  
  hc_title(text = "How the Epidemic of Drug Overdose Deaths Ripples") %>% 
  hc_legend(layout = "vertical", reversed = TRUE,
            floating = TRUE, align = "right") %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) %>% 
  hc_motion(
    enabled = TRUE,
    axisLabel = "year",
    labels = unique(as.character(df$sm)),
    series = 0,
    updateIterval = 50,
    magnet = list(
      round = "floor",
      step = 0.1
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Or, alternatively, just use `joinBy = c("iso-a3", "fips")` with the original code.

Comment: thx guys, one more question. how to replace `map` with this code `get_data_from_map(download_map_data("custom/world"))`?

Comment: You don't have the same country codes in that file as you do for the `fips` variable. You'd need to replace the country codes to join them up. It could rather easily be done (I think) since the `iso-a2` variable in the old map data contains the same mapping as the `hc-a2` variable in the new map dataset so a quick merge would fix it